# Zip Files including includeBaseDirectory in c# Error

Tags: c#, zip

Well, I have been zipping files and realized that I was missing the base directory, I was only zipping the content before adding the includeBaseDirectory option which is now giving me errors, please assist, I am still new to c#

```
private static void zipFile(string source, string destination)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(source);
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
            {
                string from = source + directory;               
                string to = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination, (directory + ".zip"));
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(from, to, CompressionLevel.Fastest, bool includeBaseDirectory, true);               
            }
        }
```

error: invalid term expression, if I remove the word bool, it says the name 'includeBaseDirectory' does not exist in current context

Comment: What error is this code throwing?

Comment: Invalid term expression bool

Comment: swap "bool includeBaseDirectory" with "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide the value of the boolean `includeBaseDirectory` that the method `CreateFromDirectory` expects (in your case `true`):

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(from, to, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
```